# Spacing in Java - 3.27.1: LAB: Number pattern

Tags: java, newline, whitespace

I don't understand how to do a new line at the end? I have included a picture that shows what my answer looks like with the whitespacing wrong and then shows how they want the output to look.

here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberPattern {
    public static void printNumPattern(int num1, int num2) {
       //print num1
       System.out.print(num1);
       //check if num1 is non-negative
       if (num1 >= 0) {
           //print a space
           System.out.print("  ");
           //recursively call printNumPattern, pass num1-num2 as new num1,
           //and same num2 as arguments
           printNumPattern(num1-num2, num2);
           //once above call is returned, print a space and then num1 again
           System.out.print(" "+num1);
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1;
        int num2;

        num1 = scnr.nextInt();
        num2 = scnr.nextInt();
        printNumPattern(num1, num2);
    }
}
```

[Java problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv0HT.png)
[image]

Comment: Suggestion: use `if (num1 < 0) return;` and then the rest of your code need not be within a conditional. Fewer levels of nested control structures are usually easier to understand.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this. Your shown code does not print any newlines. Are you sure you have remembered to save before recompiling?

Comment: These are the directions for the assignment

3.27 LAB: Number pattern
Write a recursive method called printNumPattern() to output the following number pattern.

Given a positive integer as input (Ex: 12), subtract another positive integer (Ex: 3) continually until a negative value is reached, and then continually add the second integer until the first integer is again reached. For this lab, do not end output with a newline.

Ex. If the input is: 12 3